# android calendar events removed when sync up google calendar

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I have created events in android calendar pragmatically, these events are removed by default when my android calendar syncup with google calendar. Please note my code in below

```
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.setTimeInMillis(sTime.getTime());
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.setTimeInMillis(eTime.getTime());        
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);  
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE);
    Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I want to keep my events in anroid calendar, when syncup with google calendar. How can i do this, Please help me.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem here

Comment: I found out that, in general, you have 3 calendars. The first is your gmail, the second is birthdays and the last is holidays. When I use the second or third calendar, I run into the same problem as you do. When I use the first calendar, I have no problems. Are you perhaps using the 'wrong' calendar? what is the value of calID?

Comment: No, I'm using default android calendar only. i have inserted events in default android calendar. I lost my events when i enable sync option in settings->account->google->calendar. If sync option is disabled then, everything thing this working perfect

Answer (score 2):

All calendars have field [ACCESS_LEVEL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ACCESS_LEVEL). If you write to a calendar without write access, Google will delete the event on syncing.